# uncheck checkbox using data attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, custom-data-attribute

I have a checkbox in li like

```
<ul id="anotherdata" class="live-search-list" style="display: block;">
<li class="list_items" data-search-term="systimehour    "><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1"></div><div class="col-xs-10 col-md-11"><div class="item"><div class="item-title">SysTimeHour<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" value="SysTimeHour" name="checkbox"></span></div> </div></div></div></li>
<li class="list_items" data-search-term="systimemin "><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1"></div><div class="col-xs-10 col-md-11"><div class="item"><div class="item-title">SysTimeMin<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" value="SysTimeMin" name="checkbox"></span></div>   </div></div></div></li>
```

> on other hand i have a function call where i need to uncheck the
>   selected checkbox

```
function tagremove(i)
        {
            $('.live-search-list li').each(function(){   

                var datavalue= $(this).data("search-term");
            //  alert(datavalue);
                if(datavalue==i)
                { $(this).attr("checked", false); }  }); 
        }
```

But that is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current context `this` refers to the `li` element, you'll have to find the `input` element and set its `checked` attribute instead of setting this attribute to the `li` element.

Here is an example:

```
$(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr("checked");
```

Comment: checked attribute is not there, the check box is simply check without any attribute. so in that case what to do to uncheck that

Comment: @SumitAggarwal There are some extra spaces in the `data-search-term` value, maybe that is the problem. Try `var datavalue= $(this).data("search-term").trim()`

Comment: @SumitAggarwal try   ...prop('checked', false) in place of removeAttr

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code like this (tested with your HTML sample):

```
function tagremove(i)
{
  // You can search through document by attribute name with
  // any value. So, you can pass you `i` value directrly inside selector
  $('.live-search-list [data-search-term="' + i + '"]').each(function() {
    // You can select child elements inside of this element and check it
    $(this).find('input').attr('checked', true);

    // If checkbox is checked and you want to uncheck
    $(this).find('input').attr('checked', false);
  });
}
```